# Why are my Owncloud external mount broken (10.3.2)

Tags: smb, owncloud

On a fresh install i got these errors. Could someone tell me what's wrong or what to do?

This configuration on owncloud should work but there is now a red box. The problem is that the red box does not tell what the error is.

[image]

When you go to the folder it says that the mount points are not connected:

[image]

running the command `sudo -u www-data php occ files_external:verify 74 -vvv --output=json` gives `{"status":"error","code":1,"message":null}`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to put something in the domain field, this fixed the problem for me! Literally anything, except a backslash.